# How to find if a file contains a given string using Windows command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a batch (.bat) file for windows XP to do the following:

```
If (file.txt contains the string 'searchString') then (ECHO found it!) 
ELSE(ECHO not found)
```

So far, I have found a way to search for strings inside a file using the **FIND** command which returns the line in the file where it finds the string, but am unable to do a conditional check on it.

For example, this doesn't work.

```
IF FIND "searchString" file.txt ECHO found it!
```

Nor does this:

```
IF FIND "searchString" file.txt=='' ECHO not found
```

Any Ideas on how this can be done?

Answer (score 20):

From other post:

```
    find /c "string" file >NUL
    if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto notfound
        echo found
    goto done
    :notfound
        echo notfound
    goto done
    :done
```

Use the /i  switch when you want case insensitive checking:

```
    find /i /c "string" file >NUL
```

Or something like:  if not found write to file.

```
    find /c "%%P" file.txt  || ( echo %%P >> newfile.txt )
```

Or something like:  if found write to file.

```
    find /c "%%P" file.txt  && ( echo %%P >> newfile.txt )
```

Or something like:

```
    find /c "%%P" file.txt  && ( echo found ) || ( echo not found )
```

Comment: Consider adding /i switch in order to get case-insensitive comparison. Most of the times, that's what is needed ;-)

Answer (score 9):

I've used a **DOS** command line to do this.
Two lines, actually.  The first one to make the "current directory" the folder where the file is - or the root folder of a group of folders where the file can be.  The second line does the search.

```
CD C:\TheFolder
C:\TheFolder>FINDSTR /L /S /I /N /C:"TheString" *.PRG
```

You can find details about the parameters at [this link](http://www.computerhope.com/findstr.htm).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Note: when using CD in a script, add the /D flag to allow drive switching as well as folder changing as, most of the time, it's the intended behaviour.